# Strange python csv module behavior - don't splitting records

Tags: python, csv, geonames

I'm trying to parse `cities5000.txt` from geonames.org (http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities5000.zip) with python's csv module and getting very strange behavior: `cvs` don't split all the lines in file.

for example:

```
>>> len(open('cities5000.txt').read().splitlines())
46955
>>> len(list(csv.reader(open('cities5000.txt'))))
46955
# but here comes some fun
>>>len(list(csv.reader(open('cities5000.txt'), delimiter='\t')))
46048
```

and the `'\t'` - is the actual delimiter used in this file. So there are about 900 records that just recognized as a part of some other records' fields. But everything else is fine in parsed data.

The question is: what is the reason of this and how could I escape it without splitting all these records manually?

Comment: I get different results with that file. The first two print `46957` and the last one raises an error.

Comment: @LevLevitsky the same that last one raise `_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)`

Comment: well, that's actually the same problem - it's trying to put a lot of rows into one field. Maybe, I have an old version of that file so the data differs a bit. Anyway, I have an answer already, thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default dialect also specifies a quote char, which can be used to escape newlines. You can override it with `quotechar=None`.

```
>>> len(open('cities5000.txt').read().splitlines())
46957
>>> len(list(csv.reader(open('cities5000.txt'), delimiter='\t')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)
>>> len(list(csv.reader(open('cities5000.txt'), delimiter='\t', quotechar=None)))
46957
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the default delimiter is defined by the default dialect 'excel' (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params)

I am not aware which kind of delimiters that are but I think defining the delimiter yourself gives you more control how to split your data.

I could also imagine some problems with city names and UTF8 Encoding (not sure, just as hint for further research).

EDIT: Short google search and you will find this: https://github.com/oamasood/GeonamesPy
Maybe this helps as well.